# Issues with reading tif file in Octave

Tags: image-processing, octave, tiff

I am trying to read a medical imaging data which is in `.tif` format using Octave . It so happens that only software from https://fiji.sc/ has the ability to read the medical images I have. A sample of the image that I am referring is [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B94Aw0ZxV8SFTWNXN1JvTXBQbFU) one. This image is readable in`.tif` format only in fiji. The image can also be converted to jpg image. Only after data points is visible to other image editing software. Now the issue is , I want to load it into octave and read it - at the moment it is not possible. The `imshow()` function in octave is not allowing me to visualize the given `.tif` file.

So, if anybody has experience in reading such file formats please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your linked image is a 16bit grayscale image, see `$ gm identify -verbose hello.tif`. So lets load it into GNU Octave:

```
img = imread ("hello.tif");
hist (img(:), 200);            # show histogram
```

[image: histogram of image]

Ah!, the main information of your image is in the range 0-600 (probably the image aquisition system used had 11 or 12bit resolution), so lets scale and print this part as color encoded (viridis) image:

```
imagesc (img, [0 600])
colorbar
```

[image: imagesc with viridis colormap]

Is this what you want? Of course we can also use a gray colormap, try: `colormap gray`

If this still doesn't fit your need you should really explain what you expect to see....

Comment: You might want to explain why Fiji (ImageJ) works by default. The reason is that for non 8-bit images, ImageJ only uses the max and min values of the image. One can set other values but even then, only between the max and min values. The actual limits of the data type are never used. That makes some sense because most 16bit images never came from a 16bit camera in the first place.

Comment: I am interested in denoising the image by using filters. At the moment I am not able to use` imshow( )` of octave. One of the reason I have discovered is that the image is said to be encoded in 16bit but octave only allows to show 8bit of image. So is there any successful way of using `imshow( )`.

Comment: @motiur: It isn't true that "octave only allows to show 8bit of image" as I've shown above. Your camera which took the above image has 11 or 12bit resolution which are stored as 16bit integers. So it's common to scale it into the range 0..1 for further processing. If you just use `imshow` without LIMITS it shows the value 0 as black and 2^16-1 as white but since your range of integers is 0..2000 (see my histogram) you see a almost black image. No magick here

Answer (score 0):

imread() relies on image magic to do the conversion, some versions of which can only read TIFF in 8-bit mode (giving a warning message), but when and how this happens I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me using  a .raw ṕicture converted to .tif in Fiji. I am specifically interested in several spectral analysis from my pictures which are taken illuminating with 660 and 850nm.